# How do I create a user-defined function in T-SQL that I can use on many databases?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Most of the processes I work with are based on the end of the month.I have created a user-defined function that calculates the last dat of the previous month. How do I create the function so it can be used across multiple databases?

```
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LastDayLastMonth Date;

    set @LastDayLastMonth =  convert(date,DATEADD(DAY,-day(getdate()),GETDATE()));

    RETURN @LastDayLastMonth;
END
```

Comment: If the proper permissions are in place, simply use the [fully qualified name](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx) of the function:  `server.database.schema.object`  I'm guessing you're doing everything from within the same SQL Server instance.  If that's the case, you can exclude the "server" name.

Comment: I think you need to use a CLR function instead of a UDF.

Comment: Not sure you need to go to a CLR here but an inline table valued function would perform better than a scalar function.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about function types (UDF, CLR, scalar, etc).

Comment: How do you use that function and handle the datetime problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a scalar function an inline table valued function will perform better.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetLastDayOfLastMonth()
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    RETURN 
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())) as LastDayLastMonth;
```